# Echo data in multiple iframes from a database query

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, html

I have 6 iframes in one page. A database query populates the first iframe with some rows of data. When I select any one row from this result (based on a unique key), I run another query to the database to get more information about that row.

Now, I want to display different related parts of that information in the other 5 iframes. [all the 6 iframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlKku.jpg) How do I do that?

Technologies used: HTML5/CSS/Javascript/php/SQL Server. Please see attached image for more clarity.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: I guess not using iFrames, but `JavaScript` with AJAX requests would be a lot easier. Can you use them or are you restricted to the `iframes`?

Comment: I can use AJAX.

Comment: Then the easiest would just be to query the server for the data, and then render the data that you got. Just make 6 AJAX calls if you need to

Comment: Can you provide an example of such AJAX call please?

Answer (score 0):

> This is an answer to the question asked by the original author in the comments of his question
>
> > *Can you provide an example of such AJAX call please?*

Without jQuery (Plain JavaScript)

```
function getData(url, callback) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            callback(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function useData(data) {
    // This is where you are going to use the data to display your page (tables, text, etc...)
    // /!\ `data` is still a string. If you're using JSON for example, don't forget to `JSON.parse()` before using the code.

    console.log(data);
}

// and finally call the getData function with the url and the callback
getData("myData.php", useData);
```

Using jQuery:

```
function getData(url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        success: callback,
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("AJAX error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

function useData(data) {
    // This is where you are going to use the data to display your page (tables, text, etc...)
    // This time, jQuery will do an intelligent guess and automatically parse your data. So wether you're using XML, JSON, ..., it's going to get parsed.

    console.log(data);
}

// and finally call the getData function with the url and the callback
getData("myData.php", useData);
```

Comment: Thanks @nicovank. If I understand the code, then I will make 6 calls to the database. Is that correct? I already have all the information in just one call. My issue is how to target different pieces of that information to different parts on the page. Sorry if I understood it wrong.

Comment: Oh ok in this case what does your server respond? data in the JSON format? If it's just how to set up the page to make it look like you want to it would be CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: Let me give an example. If you look at the snapshot I attached earlier, let us say that I click on session id 4579 in there. This click will initiate a query against the database to get more details about that session and will send 11 columns which I want to show as in the 2nd snapshot I am attaching here. I have all the 11 columns with me, just want to show them in different frames or windows.

Comment: hmm, can't see an option now to attach an image

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @nicovank for suggesting AJAX. This is what I did. When a row is selected in the first frame, a single query is run against the database to get the information that is needed for all the other frames. Now using AJAX, I collect all that information in a variable. Then, I decide what information needs to be shown in the other frames and use frame[i].document.write(info_to_be_displayed_for_this_frame) to display it. This is the part that I was missing. It is all working now.

Thanks for your help.